# How can I fix PostgreSQL canceling statement error on Google SQL?

Tags: django, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We have PostgreSQL instances (1 master + 1 read replica) on Google SQL. Our Django (1.11.12) application uses these databases via PostGIS engine. When we try to use the database, we saw this error message:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.
```

When I search for a solution, they generally say that I need to change **hot_standby_feedback** flag. But as you know Google SQL service has some restrictions about [settings](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags). I can't set the flag.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

If “Google SQL” allows that, you can set [`max_standby_streaming_delay`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-MAX-STANDBY-STREAMING-DELAY) to `-1` so that replication is delayed if a conflict is detected.

Then the query will not be canceled, but replication may lag if applying changes would cause a conflict.

Consider getting an “unfettered” PostgreSQL.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't support this. If I can't solve the problem, I have to stop using the service. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like set `hot_standby_feedback = on`, I'll suggest that you indicate your interest in the open [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/111777066) on Google Cloud Platform's [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) tool. That way someone can look into the [handling query conflict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hot-standby.html#HOT-STANDBY-CONFLICT) issues your Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance encountered.

I've also been monitoring an open thread in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/71336046) about making `max_standby_archive_delay` and `max_standby_streaming_delay` flags available to users to set. You can track it there as well. Hope this helps!